# how to get particular customers order

Tags: angularjs

```
           /*factory method for getting particular customers order*/
       factory.getCustomer = function(customerId) {
                for(var i=0,len=customers.length ; i<len ; i++) {
                   if(customers[i].id === parseInt(customerId)){
                       return customer[i];
                   }
                }
               return {};
           };
       return factory();

       /*Controller*/
       myApp.controller('OrdersController',['$scope','$routeParams','customersFactory', function($scope,$routeParams,customersFactory) {

           var customerId = $routeParams.customerId;
           $scope.customer = null;


           function init() {
               $scope.customer = customersFactory.getCustomer(customerId);
           }



           init();


       }]);

       /*View*/

       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h2>{{customer.name}}'s Orders</h2>
                   <table class="table table-hover">
                       <tr>
                           <th>Product</th>
                           <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="order in customer.orders">
                            <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
                            <td>{{ order.total | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>



       /*JSON FILE*/
                             {
           "id": "1",
           "joined": "2000-12-2",
           "name": "Wali",
           "city": "Dubai",
           "orderTotal": "9.0765",
           "orders": [
             {
               "id": "1",
               "product": "protein",
               "total": "11.987"
             }
           ]
         },
         {
           "id": "2",
           "joined": "2004-12-2",
           "name": "Ali",
           "city": "London",
           "orderTotal": "20.0765",
           "orders": [
             {
               "id": "2",
               "product": "bcca",
               "total": "2.3456"
             },
               {
               "id": "3",
               "product": "baseball",
               "total": "4.3456"
             }
           ]
         },
         {
           "id": "3",
           "joined": "1980-11-2",
           "name": "Zen",
           "city": "Australia",
           "orderTotal": "6.500",
           "orders": [
             {
               "id": "3",
               "product": "chocolate",
               "total": "6.4567"
             }
           ]
         }
```

I have made a **customers** table from which we can perform the **CRUD** functionality, but when I click to check the particular customer order it is redirecting me to the right view via routing but particular customers orders are not displaying.

can any one suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your JSON data, the ID is a **String**, but you are parsing it into an integer, and using ===, which will match only if the value **and** the type of the compared variables match.

You need to change the if statement, one option is:

```
if (parseInt(customers[i].id) === parseInt(customerId))
```

Another option will be:

```
if (customers[i].id == customerId)
```

And yet another option is using angular's $filter service.
You need to inject it into your factory, and than in order to get the client, you can use:

```
var customer = $filter('filter')(customers, {id: customerId.toString()}, true);
return customer.length === 1 ? customer[0] : null;
```

The **toString** part is only because your JSON data have ID as as string, and the third argument is set to true to prevent 'like' filter (default $filter behavior will return id 10 for example also if the customerId is 1).